# “Cannot open SSH Tunnel” on MySQL

Tags: mysql, ssh, amazon-ec2

I got this problem:

http://screencast.com/t/WCk9GrBUayT

at this configurations:

http://screencast.com/t/OO982VQbAz7

Any clue?

Please help!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You should always include all information needed to answer your question in the question it self, not as links. Since the links can break in the future.

Answer (score 0):

[This has been asked before on the DBA site.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3489/trying-to-use-mysql-workbench-with-tcp-ip-over-ssh-failed-to-connect)